# Validating HTML form and using the $_GET in PHP method

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to create a login where the user inputs their username and password and then on hitting the submit button the JavaScript code runs to validate that a string has been inputted. If the result is false, it should bring up `alert("...")` And if it is true it should continue with the submission.

However rather than bringing it to the linked php file when I go to validate the submission, it brings me to index.php  (which is not the file I have linked it to) giving me a 404 Error saying the link is wrong or outdated and I can't see why or where I mis-linked it.

## ////  HTML  ////

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function validateThis() {
       var username = document.getElementById('username');
       var password = document.getElementById('userpass');
       if ((username.value =="") || (password.value == "")) {
        alert("Please enter your details");
        return false;
      }

   else {
      return true;
     }
}
</script>  
</head>

<body>
    <form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="loginValidate.php" 
    method="get" onSubmit="validateThis()">

    <input type="text" name="username"/>
    <input type="password" name="userpass"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
       
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

## ////  PHP  ////

```
<?php

$username = $_GET ['username'];
echo "Hello".$username;

?>
```

Comment: We can't tell from what you've posted what's going on. It sounds like you have an incorrect file name or a badly-configured .htaccess file or something. But we can't tell because your description is unclear. Please read about [**How to Ask questions here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: is the php-file in the same folder? is the spelling correct?

Comment: @Jeff Yep, checked it a few times! I can't see what's missing.

Comment: @Ed Cottrell Sorry about that I will edit it now.

Comment: you have no `id`'s and looking at your console would have told you about that; undefined.

Comment: Using method GET, you do realize you're putting the password in the page URL? You probably want to use POST instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're checking the element by Id (`getElementById`) and should be using `getElementsByName`.
You can also use `document.forms['myForm'].username.value == ""`, i.e.:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateThis(){
  if(document.forms['myForm'].username.value == "")
  {
    alert("empty");
    return false;
  }
    return true;
}
</script>  
</head>
<body>
    <form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="" 
    method="get" onSubmit="validateThis()">
    <input type="text" name="username"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
echo !empty($_GET['username']) ? "Hello ". $_GET['username'] : "";
?>
```

[PHPFIDDLE DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/udwn-wzb7)

Comment: good spot! `getElementsByName` returns array/node list,  so you'd need to add a `[0]`

Comment: actually I've updated the answer with a better solution. tks for the feedback ;)

Comment: ...now I look silly with my odd comment...haha

Comment: It wasn't! It took me a while to spot the error too

Comment: provide the correct path to `loginValidate.php`, you can try the absolute uri `http://yousite.com/loginValidate.php`

Comment: Brilliant, your code worked!! I have added some more to the code because I am confused about how to write this part using the `null` way you have previously suggested.  I'm only a beginner so I would like to know for future reference but I'm not sure if I need to open a new thread?: 
`if ((username.value =="") || (password.value == "")) {
        alert("...");
        return false; `

Comment: Nevermind I think I figured it out: 

`if (((username.value ==null || username.value == "") || (password.value == null || password.value == ""))) {
        alert("Please enter your details");
        return false;`